# How do I simulate a browser button click in a node environment?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am building an android app which is supposed to connect to a server of mine, such that the server performs OAuth2 authentication at a third-party website. In this website there is a button which submits a form via a POST request when clicked. Clicking the button is part of the authentication process.

The problem is that the third-party website's server enforces the same-origin request policy, so a simple AJAX request with application/x-www-form-urlencoded won't do the job - it will get denied due to CORS. As it stands, the only workaround is to somehow click on that button.

How do I do this in nodejs, where there is no window, DOM, etc...?

Comment: CORS is enforced by the browser, not by http client libraries, so there is nothing preventing you from directly sending a http request from Node.

Comment: It can also be enforced by the server. In this case it will reject requests coming from other origins.

Comment: As part of CORS, the server lays down the rules by which other origins are allowed to access it, but it is the browser that enforces these rules - not the server. CORS specifically "defines a way in which a browser and server can interact to determine whether it is safe to allow the cross-origin request". It doesn't regulate server-to-server interactions at all as far as I know.

Comment: Isn't the origin of the request sent as part of the request headers? Thus the server knows where a request originates from, and has the ultimate say on whether to allow or deny that request.

Comment: Browsers set the Origin header on cross-origin requests. Again, the server just sends whatever headers are appropriate for the cors request in response, and then it is the browser which acts on that - ie enforced the rules as per the headers sent by the server

Comment: Ok thank you, this seems logical to me. I will try and see if it works.

Comment: Yes it worked by spoofing the origin). Thanks for helping. Consider adding that as an answer.

Comment: Sure. Ok, I am going to add a more formal answer in case that may be of any help to anybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS mechanism is specifically intended to regulate interactions between a browser and a server. The server sets the rules for how other origins are allowed to interact with it, but ultimately it relies on the browser to enforce these rules - and the browser actually provides the garantee that it will.

Server to server interactions on the other hand aren't subject to CORS, so you can freely interact with other origins directly from your server regardless.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS